# ¿Cómo recoger en otro controlador que he terminado de grabar con AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo unos métodos implementados referentes al audio en un controlador que le he llamado `SonidoController`.

Dentro de este tengo el método:

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag { NSLog (@"Fin grabación"); }
```

Cuando termino de grabar el audio este método es llamado gracias al "Delegado" `AVAudioRecorderDelegate`.

El problema que tengo es que quiero desde el método principal saber cuando se ha acabado de grabar y no desde el controlador.

¿Podría hacerlo con un "Completion" en lugar de crear otro delegado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta pregunta tiene varias respuestas posibles...

Podrías tener un `SonidoControllerDelegate`, que el "método principal" (no se muy bien a qué se refiere esta expresión en la pregunta) lo implemente, y desde la implementación de `-audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` en `SonidoController` se notifique a su *delegate*.

Otra opción es que el `init` de `SonidoController` tenga un parámetro adicional de tipo `ACAudioRecorderDelegate`, y se use este *delegate* cuando se crea el `AVAudioRecorder` en lugar de usar `self`. De esta forma, la implementación de `-audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` puede estar en el llamador de `SonidoController`.

Una tercera opción es usar notificaciones, y disparar una notificación particular desde `-audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` en `SonidoController`.

Cuál de estas opciones es la mejor, depende de la arquitectura de la aplicación...

Comment: Como metodo principal me referia al Main ( hilo principal) que llama a los otros métodos de las clases necesarias. Gracias por tu respuesta !

Comment: Alfinal he conseguido implementarlo en el llamador de SonidoController ! Gracias de nuevo